# Save back end form to magento database

Tags: magento2

guys I'm trying to save information in the magento 2 database, but I can't seem to find a tutorial that doesn't have an error. Can someone recommend me a good tutorial that at the end is sure to please?

Answer (score 0):

Check [magento/module-newsletter](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Newsletter) as an example. It has [form template](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml) and [controller](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Newsletter/Controller/Subscriber/NewAction.php) to save it.

More advanced example is customer [registration form](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml) and [CreatePost](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php) controller.

Comment: you don’t know a good tutorial, which in the end would surely work?